# How to type ê without pressing <C-k> e>

Tags: key-bindings, keyboard-layout, digraphs

My keyboard layout is set to international american. And to obtain the character `ê` just press `<sfhit+6> e`. However, within the vim I need to press `<C-k> e>`. Is it possible to map `<shift+6> e` to receive the `ê` on vim?

I'm using Arch Linux. And vim in Alacritty.

When I run vim with the `--clean` flag, I found that it was the following lines in my vimrc:

```
inoremap <A-j> <Esc>: m. + 1 <CR> == gi
inoremap <A-k> <Esc>: m.-2 <CR> == gi
```

Why is that?

Comment: Which operating system are you on? Do you use GVim or Vim on a terminal (in that case, which terminal)? What happens when you enter "ê"? Do you only have problems with "ê", or also with "âôáéçãüÊ" etc.? What happens if, in Insert mode, you first press `Ctrl+V` and then the sequence `Shift-6` followed by `e` to enter the "ê" character? If you start Vim with `vim --clean`, does the problem still happen?

Comment: @filbranden
Arch Linux. And vim in Alacritty.
When I run vim with the --clean flag, I found that it was the following lines in my vimrc:

`inoremap <A-j> <Esc>: m. + 1 <CR> == gi`
`inoremap <A-k> <Esc>: m.-2 <CR> == gi`

why?

Comment: I incorporated your last comment into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `<Alt-j>` sends Vim a key code that matches that of the `ê` character.

There are two somewhat common ways for a terminal to encode the "Alt" or "Meta" key. One of them is to send an ESC character followed by the character generated by the other pressed keys. (That would be `ESC j` for the `<Alt-j>` sequence.)

The other way is to turn on the 8th bit on the character sequence generated by the other keys. Key `j` produces a key code of 106 (take a look at an ASCII table if you want to see where that's from.) The 8th bit has value 128, so ORing it with the code for `j` you get 234, which turns out to be the character code for "ê". (The `<Alt-j>` sequence generates a sequence that corresponds to "ë".) One way to inspect these character codes is with the `ga` Normal mode command in Vim, which shows the character code for the character under the cursor.

So that's why your mappings are interfering with that particular character.

These days, since Unicode is everywhere and character codes produced by the keyboard driver are typically no longer restricted to 7-bit values only, the scheme of having the Alt/Meta key just flipping the 8th bit has become less convenient, but it's actually still used (and set as default) with many terminal emulators...

The scheme using ESC as a prefix is definitely better, but I'm not sure how you would configure that in your terminal emulator (assuming such a configuration setting is even available.)

Even if you can reconfigure your terminal emulator, I'm not sure if you'd also have to reconfigure Vim to only expect ESC prefix for Alt/Meta and not the 8th bit.

There are quite a few settings that interact to configure this. For instance, the `$TERM` environment variable is usually the main one configuring which terminal emulator is in use. Vim allows for overrides of many quite specific terminal features and escape sequences. There are also some terminal features that allow dynamically querying or configuring settings. One that is particularly relevant here is [modifyOtherKeys](https://vimhelp.org/map.txt.html#modifyOtherKeys), an xterm feature that allows detecting modifier keys (such as Alt/Meta, but also Control) in a way that's less restricted than what is usually available.

If you want to debug this, perhaps start by experimenting with other terminal emulators that you have available (xterm, rxvt/urxvt, Gnome Terminal, etc.) and see if they work correctly. If you do find a setting that works, you can start looking at differences between that and Alacritty to see if you can make the latter work as well.